# How can I extract specific information from the cells?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-arrayformula, regexextract

[image: Picture of what I am trying to break down]

How can I extract just the: Brand, Showroom Only Product, etc.

Comment: if suggested answers on your questions solved your issues pls accept them

Answer (score 0):

You can use **`REGEXEXTRACT`** where you can extract all characters between two known variables. The first variable can be **`Brand:`** and the second could be a **line break** - **`\n`**. This would translate into a formula like:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(C3, "Brand: (.*)\nShowroom")
```

Then you could wrap it into ArrayFormula as suggested here: **https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/132303/186471**

Comment: @audry https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers